# Angular 4 download file from URL

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I´m working with firebase, im storing images on my firebase storage and then displaying those images on the view, each image has a button that the idea is when the user press the button download the image, how can i do it, so far i haven´t been able to find i way to do this using angular, on the image object i store the `downloadUrl` that fire storage give when i upload the image and i want to use that URL to download the image

**Component**

```
    <div class="wrapper-gallery" id="photos_container">
      <div class="mix col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 item-photo" *ngFor="let photo of couplePhotos | async | sortByFavorites: sortBy | sortByTime: sortBy">
        <div class="photo">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="{{photo.data.photo_url}}" alt="{{photo.data.name}}">
          <button class="delete" (click)="deletePhoto(photo.id, photo.data.name)"><span class="icon-cross"></span></button>
          <a class="search zoom" data-fancybox="wedding" href="{{photo.data.photo_url}}"><span class="icon-search"></span></a>
          <button class="star" [ngClass]="{'start-on': photo.data.favorite == true}" (click)="toggleFavorite(photo.id, photo)"><span class="icon-star-full"></span></button>
          <button class="download" (click)="downloadImg()"><span class="icon-download"></span></button>
          <a [href]="photo.data.photo_url" download></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case some else have the same problem here i post the answer, so far this is the best way to make this using the firebase storage. in the function `userSettings` is just a string (id of the current user login) and `filename` is the name of the file to download from the firebase storage

**Download function**

```
  public downloadFile(userSettings: string, filename): void {
    this.storageRef.ref().child(`weddingDreamPhotos/${userSettings}/${filename}`)
      .getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.responseType = 'blob';
          xhr.onload = (event) => {
            /* Create a new Blob object using the response
            *  data of the onload object.
            */
            const blob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: 'image/jpg' });
            const a: any = document.createElement('a');
            a.style = 'display: none';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          };
          xhr.open('GET', url);
          xhr.send();
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle any errors
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but its throwing 

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/accounttool-dev-7f9fa.appspot.com/o/..................................................' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to the answer created by @Miguel is to use FileSaver.

While I was using AWS and the OP was using Firebase, the process is the same. Both AWS Storage and Firebase return a URL to the file that must be downloaded. To download the contents of the URL I used FileSave.

Install [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) using npm.

```
npm install --save file-saver
```

Install the the typescript types

```
npm install @types/file-saver --save-dev
```

Then in your Angular ts file import filesave

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
```

Then call

```
saveAs(url, filename);
```

This does the same as the accepted answer, but less effort, and the code base is maintained with a bunch of additional nice to use functions.

Comment: these steps didn't download the file for me. it just opens the file in another tab

Answer (score 2):

You can create a button like that

```
<a [href]="image.downloadUrl" download></a>
```

Comment: No in this case still having the action, open the image in another tab

Comment: I just tried this at my project and worked. Could you post the rest of the code? And where did you put the a tag?

Comment: i was checking why your code is not working for me and for you is working, and find that the download attribut on 'a' element only works in google chrome but in firefox doesn´t, that´s why on firefox send to a new tab, so may you must be using google chrome or any other browser.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
download(url, downloadName) {
    leta = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = downloadName;
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
```

Comment: No, just open the image in a new tab.

Comment: at the a.download, give a name with exstension somthing like "img.png" 
 https://jsfiddle.net/8japas6a/1/

Comment: the name of the image already have the extension on the name but still having the same action, it just open the image in another windows.

Answer (score 0):

you can download xml file in angular like this:-

```
exportXml(license: any) {
    this.licenseService
          .getEncryptLicense(license.LFDNR)
          .subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.downloadFile(
              res[0].LICENSE_DATA,
              `${license.TYPE}.xml`,
              "text/xml"
            );
          });
      }

      downloadFile(content: any, fileName: any, contentType: any) {
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        const file = new Blob([content], { type: contentType });
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as fs from 'file-saver';
   
 downloadFile(url) {
            var filename = url.split('/').pop();
            try {
                fs.saveAs(url, filename);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        }
```