# Download image from URL which is in Response

Tags: angular, rest, typescript

I am trying to download image in Angular 4. I am getting a URL in response. When I click that, I can see the image which I further want to download it. I have gone through all of the Stack Overflow questions but could find out the best possible solution. So far I have tried this. This works but when I download image, I m getting a something weird instead of actual image (jpg).

```
Component.ts
-----------------------------------------------
  download(url, downloadName) {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "downloadName";
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  }
-----------------------------------------------
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513471/angular-4-download-file-from-url?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: What is the content of the file you get? What is "Something weird"?

Comment: I am getting one URL. when i hit that in browser, i can see the picture which i want to downlod but when i use above (Brandon's suggested), I can download image but when i open that, i get invalid image message..

Comment: But what are the actual contents of the file? Open it in editor and look.

Comment: @kvetis..it is a jpg file which i want to download..